# Update a Google Sheet of another Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

My need is to update a remote sheet of another user, then I first need to retrieve the file, but then how can I use the file to retrieve the relevant sheet?

Following my code:

```js
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('ImportBooks');
var range = ss.getRange('A2:M');
var data = range.getValues();

//Destination Range - Tab 1, Range 1
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1VnhUR4NpY8NOtDylo4tKrX-OsBIe4jBmv9KmhxworeI");  
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ts = sheet.getSheetByName('yourBooks');  
ts.getRange(lastRow(ts, 1), 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `DriveApp`. You can just get the target spreadsheet file by using `SpreadsheetApp.openById(file_id)`.

Try this:

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('ImportBooks');
var range = ss.getRange('A2:M');
var data = range.getValues();

//Destination Range - Tab 1, Range 1
var file_id = "1VnhUR4NpY8NOtDylo4tKrX-OsBIe4jBmv9KmhxworeI";
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file_id);
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
ts.getRange(lastRow(ts, 1), 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

References:

[SpreadsheetApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: Hi Marios, actually I'm looking for a solution that would write over a Spreadsheet that is not mine, and as far as I know through openbyId is not more possible to do it, that's why I was looking for a different solution.

Comment: @trisixnine if you have edit access to the target spreadsheet file, you can use the code I provided. There is no solution that would allow a user to edit a file of another user without the edit permission of the latter. Please confirm that you have edit access to the target spreadsheet, run my code and then let me know if it worked for you.